# Does multiplication by a positive definite matrix preserve eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a positive definite matrix and let $B$ a matrix.

Then, $AB$ is similar to $A^{\frac{1}{2}}BA^{-\frac{1}{2}}$, which is in turn similar to $B$, so I get that $AB$ and $B$ are similar. Hence, $AB$ and $B$ have the same eigenvalues.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Think about what went wrong if you set $B=I$. Because I assume you know that $A$ does not need to have all eigenvalues equal to $1$.

Comment: If I set $B=I$, then I can see the problem. But, if $A$ is positive definite, then $A^{1/2}$ well defined as a positive definite matirx?

Comment: $AB \sim A^{1/2}BA^{1/2} \not \sim A^{1/2}BA^{-1/2} \sim B$

Comment: Why is $AB$ similar to $A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}$?

Comment: @hl0202 How did you prove that $AB$ is similar to $A^\frac12BA^{-\frac12}$?

Comment: @5xum I screwed up the sign. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:

If all steps were correct, then the answer would be yes. You already know ($A=4I, B=I$) that the answer is no.

Therefore, there is a mistake in one of the two "they are similar" statements.

The second statement looks pretty rock solid. The matrix
$$A^{1/2}BA^{-1/2}$$
is clearly similar to $B$.

---

Therefore, the mistake must be...

Comment: Why is $A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}$ similar to B? Shouldn't it be $A^{1/2}BA^{-1/2}$ or $A^{-1/2}BA^{1/2}$?

Comment: @hl0202 Sorry, I forgot a minus.

Comment: Got it. Thx very much

Comment: @hl0202 Those signs are a pain in the a**. But hey, at least you figured out that something is fishy. I hope my example also showed you how to isolate your mistake.

Comment: If $A$ is the identity matrix, then A obviously preserves the eigenvalues. And my feeling is that the identity matrix is the only matrix which preserves the eignvalues?

Comment: @hl0202 I'm not sure. Maybe unitary matrices? I cant remember from the top of my head.